# How to disable a specific branch in a Jenkins Multibranch job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have a multibranch job in my Jenkins, and it has been running on multiple branches over the last few months.
Now I finished working on some of the branches, and I want to prevent them from running again, but I didn't find a way to disable a branch. 
Is there any way I can disable a specific branch without disabling the whole job?

Comment: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3400/how-to-disable-some-branches-in-multibranch-jenkins-builds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, that's possible. On the multibranch pipeline configuration, click **Add** -> **Filter by name**.
Then, you can add the branch you want to disable on the Exclude  text box, it will appear cross out on the multibranch view page.
If you already use the **Filter by name (with wildcard)** for example, removing the branch name from the Include text box will disable the specific branch as well.